# get label value from checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Everyone I want to capture label name(72*30) using the following code:

```js
$("input[type = 'radio']:checked:last").each(function() {
  var idVal = $(this).attr("id");
  var a = $("label[for='"+idVal+"']").text();
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="radio">
  <input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills dimension-layer-dimension  tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" type="radio">
  <label id="tmcp_radio_9" >72*30</label> 
  <span class="price tc-price  hidden">
    <span class="amount">20 <i class="fa fa-inr"></i></span>
  </span>  
</li>
```

But the code doesn't `alert` anything. What is wrong?

Comment: you can directly get the value using id..? then why

Comment: You have given an id to label and can access directly using $("#tmcp_radio_9").text()

Comment: @KeerthiVasan i have three radio button id is generating dynamically same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `next()` because your `label` is after (next) your `input`

```
$("input[type='radio']:checked:last").next().text()
```

Hope this will help you.

You can see demo **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/ma9ep068/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this keyword

```
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {

   var a= $(this).next().text();
   alert(a);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also

```
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {

   var a= $(this).closest("label").text();
   alert(a);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
var lb =  $('#tmcp_radio_9').text();
```